# Formatter VS DateFormat inconsistencies

Tags: java, formatting, simpledateformat, date-formatting

**Premise**

This question might be reasonably deemed as too broad or opinion-driven, but I feel I've got to risk it anyway.

**Problem**

There is a number of incomprehensible inconsistencies between the date/time conversion formats illustrated in Java's [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt) VS [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) APIs.

For instance:

- `M` represents the minute in `Formatter` but the month in `SimpleDateFormat` **and vice-versa**
- `S` and `L` respectively represent second and millisecond in `Formatter`, but `s` and `S` respectively represent second and millisecond in `SimpleDateFormat`
- `A` and `a` respectively represent the long/short name of the day in week in `Formatter` but the same output in `SimpleDateFormat` is represented by `<= 2` vs `> 2` consecutive occurrences of `E`, while `a` represents the AM/PM marker instead, in `SimpleDateFormat`
- Etc.

**Question**(s)

- Is there some rationalization justifying these inconsistences, e.g. maybe the two classes use different standards?
- I can only infer from `Formatter`'s API that:

  > The types are similar to but not completely identical to those defined by GNU date and POSIX `strftime(3c)`.
- `SimpleDateFormat` does not seem to bother even mentioning the rationale for its conventions
- Are these two conventions arbitrary **and** inconsistent by design, or are there implicit standards that I am not aware of, that justify these inconsistences?

Comment: It closely resemble what became the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table). (`SimpleDateFormat` was in Java 1.0 IIRC, so released in 1996, while that standard is much more recent). `DateTimeFormatter` matches also its latest version (although some patterns declared in it are not supported by `DateTimeFormatter`).

Comment: [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) is the class referenced in comment above by Tunaki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SimpleDateFormat**

As @Tunaki has stated, `SimpleDateFormat` uses pattern characters defined by the [Date Field Symbol Table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) (which is standardized by [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), or *Unicode Common Locale Data Repository*).

This project is widely used by many companies, such as Google, IBM, Microsoft, Apple, etc. in order to accomplish extensive standard repository of locale data, and so software internationalization and localization. That's why some date/time patterns are very similar to others from different programming languages.

Also, besides of ruling the [way we use date, time and time zone](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Contents), it is very important to specify standards for collations, keyboard mappings, numbers, currencies, etc. Moreover, it defines what's gonna happen when we try to parse dates in Japanese, e.g.

In order to understand this, we must state [what means a "parsing" process](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime):

> - A mapping between a point in time (UDate) and a set of calendar fields, which in turn depends on:
>
>   - The rules of a particular calendar system (e.g. Gregorian, Buddhist, Chinese Lunar)
>   - The time zone
> - A mapping between a set of calendar fields and a formatted textual representation, which depends on the fields selected for display,
>     their display style, and the conventions of a particular locale.

So, that's necessary to know that a skeleton of `"MMMMdjmm"` might result in the following format patterns for different locales:

```
Locale | format pattern
------ | ---------------------
en_US  | "MMMM d 'at' h:mm a"
es_ES  | "d 'de' MMMM, H:mm"  
ja_JP  | "M月d日 H:mm"
```

---

**Formatter**

The reason why `Formatter` "adopted" different formatting patterns is because this class is supposed to be an interpreter for printf-style format strings, which is very much close to [GNU date](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html#SEC123) and [POSIX `strftime(3c)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) realities (as the [official docs states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)).

From GNU docs:

> The output of the `date` command is not always acceptable as a date
>   string, not only because of the language problem, but also because
>   there is no standard meaning for time zone items like 'IST'.
>
> When using date to generate a date string intended to be parsed later,
>   specify a date format that is independent of language and that does
>   not use time zone items other than 'UTC' and 'Z'.

Let's take a look at a simple date/time example with GNU:

```
TZ=UTC0 date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ'
// Output: 2004-03-01 00:21:42Z
```

Pay attention to the printf-style as well as the use of same conversion characters of `Formatter` class.

However, the docs also says that they're just similar, not identical. That's because Java opted for some flexibility for specific fields, like in `'z'` case:

> [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) style numeric time zone offset from GMT, e.g. -0800. This
>   value will be adjusted as necessary for Daylight Saving Time.